# How can you create a registration form for an already existing template? Django

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to create a registration form but for a template that I've already build. The problem is that such template doesn't detect Django's prebuild form methods and the form isn't saved when the user enters his details. How can you fix this?

template:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Login</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href='{% static "vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
      <link href='{% static "css/sb-admin-2.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block bg-register-image"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="p-5">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Create an Account!</h1>
                            </div>
                            <form class="user" method="POST">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName"
                                            placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleLastName"
                                            placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputEmail"
                                        placeholder="Email Address">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                            id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                            id="exampleRepeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href={% url 'register' %} class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                                    Register Account
                                </a>
                                <hr>
                                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">
                                    <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Register with Google
                                </a>
                                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i> Register with Facebook
                                </a>
                            </form>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a class="small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a class="small" href="login.html">Already have an account? Login!</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src='{% static "vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" %}'></script>
  <script src='{% static "vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" %}'></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src='{% static "vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js" %}'></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
      <script src='{% static "js/sb-admin-2.min.js"}'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

views.py(register function):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render
from .scraper import EmailCrawler
from django.http import HttpResponse
from celery import shared_task
from multiprocessing import Process
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import CreateUserForm

def register(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')
    else:

        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Account was created for' + user)
                return redirect('login')
    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'leadfinderapp/register.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Order
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Any help would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: From your html, it seems like you are not using the rendered form. Also ,your custom inputs do not have the 'name' attribute hence none of the inputs are submitted. The second part may be why your form isn't working

Comment: how can you use the rendered form?

Comment: just include `{{ form }}` into your html `form` tag. Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/

Comment: yeah, but that way the customized CSS gets deleted. Right?

Comment: The input will be rendered in Django's default style. You can include the relevant names in your custom input in the html to maintain the current styling. i.e.`<input name="first_name" ... >`  The documentation also has more ways of dealing with input that may still retain your styles